# Seleium/Ruby - can't access save button in a modal popup

Tags: ruby, selenium

For the life of me I cannot get control of anything in this modal. I just want to click on this dang save button.

[image: and a screenshot (unfortunately it's a proprietary internal site)]

For all the other modals that are like this I am able to use this code successfully:

```
@driver.switch_to.frame @driver.find_element(:xpath, "//*[contains(@name, 'modal')]")
```

I get a not found error this time around though.

Here's the html of the modal i'm trying to access -NOTE the modal number changes so I can't hard code modal3:

and here's the html for the button:

```
<html class=" ext-strict">
<head>
<body class=" ext-gecko ext-gecko2" keydownhandlerset="true">
<div id="patientChartsContainer">
<div id="patientSearch" style="display:none">
<div class="tooltipWrapper">
<div id="patientPhotoContainer"></div>
<div id="modalWindowContainer" class="">
<div class="axShadowLayer window local" style="display: block; width: 558px; height: 453px; left: 384px; right: auto; top: 228px; z-index: 1010;">
<div class="axShadowTopRow">
<div class="axShadowMiddleRow">
<div class="axShadowBottomRow">
<div class="axShadowContentLayer">
<div class="priModalWrapper">
<ul class="priModalHeader">
<div class="priModalContentBackground"></div>
<ul class="priModalFooter">
<div class="priModalContentWrapper">
<div class="priModalContentContainer">
<iframe id="modal1" class="windowFrame" name="modal1" src="/chart/ui/desktop/patientCharts/chartSummary/chartNote/createChartNote/createNoteModal.html" allowtransparency="true" frameborder="0">
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html class=" ext-strict" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<body class=" ext-gecko ext-gecko2" keydownhandlerset="true">
<div id="newNoteContainer" class="newEncounterNote">
<ul class="newNoteOptions">
<div class="axModalButtonsFooter">
<div class="footerButtonsWrapperRight">
<div class="buttonClass axSaveButton">
<span>Save</span>
```

I've tried a few things and variations of what I have below:

```
#@driver.find_element(:xpath, "//div[@id='modalWindowContainer']/div/div[4]/div/ul/li/div[2]/div[3]").click
#@driver.switch_to.frame @driver.find_element(:xpath, "//*[contains(@name, 'modal')]")
#@driver.switch_to.default_content
#@driver.switch_to.frame(@driver.find_element(:class, 'windowFrame'))
#@driver.find_element(:css, "div.buttonClass.axSaveButton").click
#@driver.switch_to.frame @driver.find_element(:class, 'windowFrame') 
#@driver.find_element(:xpath => "//button/span[contains(text(),'Save')]").click
```

/html/body/div[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/koKcq.png)/div/div/div/span

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
#@driver.switch_to.default_content
#@driver.switch_to.frame @driver.find_element(:class, 'windowFrame')
#@driver.find_element(:css, "div.buttonClass.axSaveButton > span").click
```

This will:

1. reset the frame context
2. find the proper iframe
3. Click on the **span** (which has the save text, and might hold the listener) element in the `<div class="buttonClass axSaveButton">` tag

Comment: Unfortunately not working.  Error: test_CreateAndVerifyPatient(Createnewpatient): Selenium::WebDriver::Error::NoSuchElementError: Unable to locate element: .windowFrame

Comment: Do you execute the given lines after having opened the iframe?
If so, have you tried to add a `when_present` condition?

Source: http://www.seleniumframework.com/basic-tutorial/wait_commands/

Comment: I do execute the given lines after opening the frame, that's a good thought but unfortunately I still get error: test_CreateAndVerifyPatient(Createnewpatient):
  Selenium::WebDriver::Error::NoSuchElementError: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"buttonClass.axSaveButton>span"}
    (Session info: chrome=55.0.2883.87)

Comment: I see `"selector":"buttonClass.axSaveButton>span"` in your comment, but I proposed `"div.buttonClass.axSaveButton > span"` for the selector (see the "div." at the beginning and the spaces around the ">" ). Does that help?